# how to update and delete row from SQLitedatabase?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to android developing , while I developing notepad application in front page `listview` contains item as title of notes , i want to update and delete a row from the `listview`:

```
public void Update(String txt)
    {
    ContentValues upateValues = createContentValues(txt);
    db.update(table_name, upateValues, row + "="+ "a", null);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Record Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

public void Delete()
    {
    db.delete(table_name, "row" +"="+"jmj", null);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Record Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Display();
    }
```

Is this query correct for update and delete operation?

Answer (score 1):

You have two (main) options how to do that:

1) Use rawQuery and write update/delete like in any other DB engine.

```
db.rawQuery("UPDATE table_name SET column1=value, column2=value2 WHERE some_column=some_value")
```

2) Use "helper" methods and do it like this:
Update:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("your new values");
db.update(TABLE, values, ID + "=?", new String[] { rowId });
```

Delete:

```
db.delete(TABLE, ID + " =? ", new String[] { intId });
```

Don't forget to tell your listview that dataset has changed. How to do that depends on which Adapter you are using for you ListView. I suppose that you don't use ContentProvider/Loader so simple adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() should help.